# Eclipse: how to set XML indentation type for a specific project only?

Tags: xml, eclipse, coding-style

Usually I use 4 spaces per indentation level. Some projects however, use something different, like 1 tab. How do I configure this setting on a per project basis to override the workspace default?

The code style/format settings for Java allow for the creation of profiles. There seems to be no such thing for XML.